# Emacs/AUCTeX: Rewriting the Okular-make-url function to work with new synctex (full path + "./") syntax

Tags: emacs, latex, lisp, elisp, auctex

**The basic problem:**

Need to write an Emacs lisp function that handles forward search from a TeX file in Emacs to a line in the PDF output corresponding to the current position within the TeX file. Synctex allows for this sort of operation. However, synctex files are referenced differently as of the new version of TeXlive 2011, requiring writing of the Emacs function.

**Background:**

Synctex in TeXlive 2011 uses a different syntax for referring the TeX sources (technically, I suppose it has to do with the way pdflatex in TeXlive 2011 creates synctex files). In TeXlive 2010 TeX sources are just referenced using a relative path; in TeXlive 2011 TeX sources are referenced using `/full/path/to/tex/source/./tex-source-file.tex`.

In any case, this makes the forward search from TeX source in Emacs to pdf output in Okular break. One way of doing forward search in Emacs to Okular involved a function like:

```
(defun okular-make-url () (concat
    "file://"
    (expand-file-name (funcall file (TeX-output-extension) t)
        (file-name-directory (TeX-master-file)))
    "#src:"
    (TeX-current-line)
    (TeX-current-file-name-master-relative)))
```

(and

```
 (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
       '("%u" okular-make-url))

 (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
```

)

This generates a command like:

```
okular --unique my-file.pdf#src:88my-file.tex
```

Which, as of TeXlive 2010, correctly jumps to the line in the pdf output corresponding to line 88 of the TeX input. But, as discussed above, it doesn't work with TeXlive 2011, due to the new way of handling synctex paths to TeX sources.

**What is needed:**

What is needed is a rewriting of `okular-make-url` which generates something like:

```
okular --unique my-file.pdf#src:88/full/path/to/my/tex/source/./my-file.tex
```

I.e., with (1)the full path of the file + (2)"./" + (3)the file-name.

I'm not adept enough with Emacs lisp commands (and AUCTeX elisp code in particular) to be sure of how to do this. Obviously, it has to do with changing the last part of the `okular-make-url` function.

Suggestions?

Comment: belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116633/6185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

1. Update to latest version of Okular (v0.13) - this may or may not be necessary.
2. Define new expander to get current directory of TeX source:

   1. Go to "Customize AUCTeX" choose "TeXCommand" then go to "TeX Expand List" and add one:
   2. Add:

      - Key: `%(dir)`
      - Expander: `(lambda nil default-directory)`
3. In your .emacs, instead of

   ```
   (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b")))
   ```

   use:

   ```
   (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%(dir)./%b")))
   ```

from:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274294#c18

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by BeSlayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904563/712605) does not work for me when the `.tex` file being edited is in a different directory than `TeX-master`.  The following does work:

1. Define new expander to get current directory of TeX source:

   1. `M-x customize-variable <RET> TeX-expand-list <RET>`
   2. Add a new entry to the list:

      - Key: `%(masterdir)`
      - Expander: `(lambda nil (expand-file-name (TeX-master-directory)))`
      - Arguments: none
2. Define a new view program for Okular:

   1. `M-x customize-variable <RET> TeX-view-program-list <RET>`
   2. Add a new entry to the list:

      - Name: `Okular`
      - Choice: Command
      - Command: `okular --unique %o#src:%n%(masterdir)./%b`
3. Configure Okular as the PDF viewer:

   1. `M-x customize-variable <RET> TeX-view-program-selection <RET>`
   2. For `output-pdf` change the viewer to `Okular`

Or you can put the following in your `.emacs`:

```
;; use Okular to view AUCTeX-generated PDFs
(push '("%(masterdir)" (lambda nil (expand-file-name (TeX-master-directory))))
      TeX-expand-list)
(push '("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%(masterdir)./%b")
      TeX-view-program-list)
(push '(output-pdf "Okular") TeX-view-program-selection)
```